# What do progeny of ragnorra look like?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I am writing a campaign in 5e that takes inspiration from the elder evil Ragnorra from 3.5.  I understand the sign warps things into aberrations, but don’t quite know what would be the specific changes to the character’s forms. I am not asking for stats, just the physical changes that would occur to players and NPCs.

I am trying to go off of what the book has for whatever I can use in 5e.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but you're going to need to dial it in a bit before we can really help you.  What specifically are you asking for help with here?  If the question you intend is the question on the title, you should also make it clearly in the message body.  Also, if it is just a matter of appearance, it sounds like this is a 3.5 question and not a 5e question.

Comment: In the book, it describes that they’re warped into aberrations, but it doesn’t say what the alterations to the player’s forms are

Comment: If I understand correctly, the Elder Evils entry on Ragnorra already describes physical symptoms of Ragnorra's effects. Beyond that what are you stuck on? It may help to indicate which passage from Elder Evils implies physical effects you're not sure about.

Comment: I’m talking about change in appearance, not stats

Comment: I’m unsure if the blemishes, warts, and pustules are the only changes.